# Is there a way to send a SMS without having to purchase a number?

Tags: sms

I have an app that monitors the temperature of my beer batch and wants me if it starts tp warm up. I would like to receive an SMS when this happens. Is it possible to send an SMS with twilio without having to pay a monthly charge for a number? Prepaying for the SMS messages is not the issue, but I have no interest in replying to messages.

Comment: You can use Api's for that. There is a useful api for that's on rapidApi link: https://rapidapi.com/collection/free-sms-apis.

Comment: Receiving SMS's still takes up network capacity.